# Automatically Refreshing R Shiny Application - R

Tags: r, shiny, localhost

I have a locally hosted shiny application. The application pulls data from a data feed and allows plotting and elementary stats. However, I am having trouble getting this app to refresh. I tried setting Task Scheduler to run the following every 6-hours:

```
ip="10.30.27.127" 
runApp("//COB-LOGNETD-01/LoggerNet/R_Scripts/shiny",host=ip,port=4438)
```

However, despite this executing, it does not refresh. Is there a way to get the shiny app to refresh automatically?

Comment: thats should be possible within shiny i guess, can you describe the data feed?

Comment: just many text files that are continually appended to. very simple.

Comment: ok, have you looked into `invalidateLater()` already?

Comment: i have now! so if i am reading this correctly, by putting `invalidateLater(2000)` within the server script it will automatically update. While this is great, unfortunately, all of the pre-processing of the data and reading it comes before the `shinyServer(function(input,output){` function. so  i am not sure this will solve my problems.

Comment: and you cant integrate the preprocessing within a `reactive()` function?

Comment: hmm. i can but it takes 20 seconds to load when changing the plot.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480206/how-to-update-ui-on-file-change

Comment: thanks, this does help. i think i will automate the data pre-processing in a separate script and use task scheduler to execute this at regular intervals. and then re-read in the data within the server script. this way the user wont be having to wait. thanks @BigDataScientist