# Make a dynamically `renderUI` using a reactive function?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a html file which I want to update on the shiny server as soon as I updated it on the server.

```
myapp
 |_server.R
 |_ui.R
 |_exp.html
```

My `server.R` looks like:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$inc <- renderUI(includeHTML("./exp.html"))
....}
```

and my `ui.R` looks like

```
tabItem("tabGlossar",  
              fluidRow(box(htmlOutput("inc"), width =12))
              
      )
```

How can I make dynamicallly `renderUI` so that after putting `exp.html` on the server, like all other elements in `server.R`, the change in `exp.html`  would be visible? I cannot use `renderUI` within a `reactive` function, true?

Comment: Maybe check out the `?reactiveFileReader` function. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480206/how-to-update-ui-on-file-change. Even those you are not reading the file as a data source, you can still track it when it changes and run some code by observing the reactive value.